# MSI X350 wifi stopped working

Tags: 11.10, wireless, laptop, msi

I have a dual-boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 on my MSI X350.

During the installation process and some time after the wireless worked just fine and I used the internet connection to install updates and everything.

(I think) because of the distance to the router I sometimes had to reconnect manually (click on the wireless button in the syslink and then click on my wifi network), but that was ok.

The problem is that one time I could not reconnect so I shut the wifi off and on again to try another reconnect, but since then I wasn't able to reconnect to the wifi and now I cannot even switch on the wifi anymore (it seems permanently disabled or something). Under Win7 however, everything works fine (wifi connection and internet, as before).

tl;dr : My wifi used to work under Win7 and Ub11.10 and then stopped working under Ub11.10.

Info/Hardware(hopefully it's readable, because I had to save the logs and open them again under Win7 and the formation was lost):

**iwconfig**

> lo
>   no wireless extensions.
>
> eth0
>   no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan0
>   IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
>   Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm
>   Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>   Power Management:off

**sudo lshw -C network**

> *-network

```
  - description: Ethernet interface
  - product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
  - vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
  - physical id: 0
  - bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
  - logical name: eth0
  - version: 02
  - serial: 40:61:86:bc:1e:f6
  - size: 10Mbit/s
  - capacity: 1Gbit/s
  - width: 64 bits
  - clock: 33MHz
  - capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
  - configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
  - resources: irq:42 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:feaff000-feafffff   memory:fdff0000-fdffffff memory:feac0000-feadffff
```

> *-network DISABLED

```
  - description: Wireless interface
  - product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
  - vendor: Ralink corp.
  - physical id: 0
  - bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
  - logical name: wlan0
  - version: 00
  - serial: 6c:62:6d:1a:3a:dd
  - width: 32 bits
  - clock: 33MHz
  - capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  - configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.0.0-13-generic firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
  - resources: irq:19 memory:febf0000-febfffff
```

**sudo lspci -nn**

> - 00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a40] (rev 07)
>
>   - 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07)
>   - 00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a43] (rev 07)
>   - 00:1a.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1a.1 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2938] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1a.7 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:293c] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 [8086:2946] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1d.1 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1d.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1d.7 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev 93)
>   - 00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation ICH9M-E LPC Interface Controller [8086:2917] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E SATA AHCI Controller [8086:2929] (rev 03)
>   - 00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:2930] (rev 03)
>   - 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
>   - 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3090]

**rfkill list all**

> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
>      Soft blocked: no
>      Hard blocked: no

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: What is the output from: **sudo lshw -C network** and **iwconfig**?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, I added the logs that seemed relevant.

Comment: please add `rfkill list all` to your question.

Comment: ok, added rfkill list all

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I resolved the problem myself.
My wifi is switched off after boot up and I just didn't switch it on. No wonder I didn't get a connection.
Thanks for your time.